# Area with geometry triangular

Tags: graphics

Is there a fuction suitable for if to calculate this kind geometry?

I used the formula for the area of the triangle

[image]

```
p1={0,0};
p2={24,50};
p3={86,110};
p4={120,0};
pointDistance=RegionNearest[Line[{p3,p4}],p2];
lineBlack=Line[{p1,p2,p3,p4,p1}];
lineRed={Dashed,Red,Line[{p2,p4}]};
lineDistance={Dashed,Red,Line[{p2,pointDistance}]};
Graphics[{lineBlack,lineRed,lineDistance}]
area1=(EuclideanDistance[p1,p4]*p2[[2]])/2//N
area1=(EuclideanDistance[p2, pointDistance]*EuclideanDistance[p3, p4])/2//N
areaTotal=area1+area2
```

[image: IMAGEM]

Comment: Very intelligent reasoning, but the code is very large.

Comment: I also found it, but I had no idea of ​​the possibilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `Polygon` and function `Area` where this use "Region".

```
poly = Polygon[{p1, p2, p3, p4}];
Graphics[poly]
```

[image: IMAGEM]

```
Area[poly]
```

> 7430